# copy a range to another workbook using row and column number?

Tags: vba, excel

i want to copy a range of cells of a particular row and column number to specific worksheet of a workbook.

```
Sub test()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks("Book4.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks("Book5.xlsx")
y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Paste = x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: You got the **Copy >> Paste** a little mixed-up, use `x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)).Copy Destination:= 
y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")`.  If you want to copy only the values, then use: `y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value = x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)).Value`

Comment: you can simplify it to `x.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` since Excel will extend the pasted area accordingly to the copied one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34886033/4539709