# Copying data to new worksheet throws 'Subscript out of range'

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a module in VBA that is supposed to:

- Opens a dialog box where another Excel file is chosen for import
- Copies the data from the sheet called "Rapport" in the selected file (the sheet is always called "Rapport" since it is an exported file which is always formatted in the same way)
- The copied data are pasted into a new sheet which is renamed "Data".

When I run the module I get an error saying

> 'Subscript out of range'

So the dialog box opens, I can choose a file, open it, but when it comes to copy/pasting the data it fails.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Import()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim txtFilePath As String
    Dim txtFileName As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        'Title of dialog box.
        .Title = "Select a file"

        If .Show = True Then
            txtFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    txtFileName = fso.GetFileName(txtFilePath)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=txtFilePath

    'The workbook, the data is pasted to, is called "Rapport_auto"
    Workbooks(txtFileName).Worksheets("Rapport").Copy _
        after:=Workbooks("Rapport_auto").Worksheets(1)

    'Change name of active sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

    'Close imported workbook
    Workbooks(txtFileName).Close
End Sub
```

Is there any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

//UPDATE// During debugging I fixed the problem - see reply below.

Comment: on what line do you get the error when debugging?

Answer (score 0):

*Is there any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?*

The second workbook `(Rapport_auto)` is not opened. 
[Copying a worksheet to another workbook using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266597/copying-a-worksheet-to-another-workbook-using-vba)

Comment: @Jeeped - you can, I was thinking about some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

@Vityata, the 'Rapport_auto'-file is the file that I am running the code from, so it should be open.

However, I just solved the problem - I don't know why it is working better, but the solution was to change the code to:

```
Dim currentFileName As String

currentFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set Wb = Workbooks(currentFileName)

Workbooks(txtFileName).Worksheets("Rapport").Copy _
    after:=Wb.Worksheets(1)
```

Instead of just

```
Workbooks(txtFileName).Worksheets("Rapport").Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("Rapport_auto").Worksheets(1)
```

I was splitting the code up in an attempt to debug smaller bits, but in the end it just worked :)