# Macro Merge file with different header

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on 2 different sheets which are Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Right now, I have managed to combined 2 sheet if the column header in both files is the same. So how to merge into a combined file which select specific column.

The problem I have right now is the header between 2 sheet is different so it is hard for me to merge 2 different header but it contains same type of data. For example Sheet1 use First Name as its column header and Sheet2 uses Nickname as its column header.

I also don't want it copy the entire column since it contain insignificant column to merged.

I attach the expected result for reference.

[image]

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3k thanks for edit it. I hope you can assist me in solving this problem.

Comment: Just because I could do a tidy-up on your question doesn't mean I will be able to answer it.  (I have no real idea how to write code to guess as to which column header in one sheet matches which column header in another sheet - I would just hardcode that sort of thing if I was doing it.)  But hopefully someone will come along some time in the near future and make a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you know what Columns your data is in then you can work with Sheets/Columns with simple Do Until Loop*

*See Example / and see comment on the code*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim B As Range, _
        C As Range, _
        D As Range, _
        E As Range, _
        F As Range, _
        G As Range ' Columns on Sheet1 & Sheet2

    Dim i%, x% ' Dim as long

    Dim Sht As Worksheet  ' Every Sheet on This Workbook
    Dim Comb As Worksheet ' Combine Sheet

    Set Comb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combine")

    i = 2 ' Start on row 2 - Sheet1 & Sheet2
    x = 2 ' Start on row 2 - Combine sheet

    'Looping through the worksheets in the workbook
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' ignore Sheet "Combine"
        If Sht.Name <> "Combine" Then
            Debug.Print Sht.Name ' Print on Immediate Window

            Set B = Sht.Columns(2)
            Set C = Sht.Columns(3)
            Set D = Sht.Columns(4)
            Set E = Sht.Columns(5)
            Set F = Sht.Columns(6)

            Do Until IsEmpty(B.Cells(i))

                Comb.Columns(1).Cells(x).Value = B.Cells(i).Value
                Comb.Columns(2).Cells(x).Value = C.Cells(i).Value
                Comb.Columns(3).Cells(x).Value = D.Cells(i).Value
                Comb.Columns(4).Cells(x).Value = E.Cells(i).Value
                Comb.Columns(5).Cells(x).Value = F.Cells(i).Value

                i = i + 1
                x = x + 1
            Loop

        End If

        i = 2 ' Reset 1st Loop

    Next

    ' Auto-Fit Rows & Columns
    With Comb.Cells
        .Rows.AutoFit
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

*See also examples on [copy/paste - values = values - PasteSpecial method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886033/4539709)*

*Also see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4539709)*

Answer (score 0):

I have added to your code and commented it. I hope this helps.

```
Sub Combine()

    Dim J As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range            ' specify a range to copy
    Dim R As Long               ' set a variable to calculate a row number

'    On Error Resume Next       ' You want to see the errors and fix them
                                ' therefore don't suppress them
'    Sheets(1).Select           ' you don't need to "select" anything
'    Worksheets.Add             ' instead of adding a sheet I suggest you
                                ' you create a copy of Shhet(1)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    ' the new sheet will now be the "ActiveSheet"
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = "Combined"
        ' delete all the columns you don't want to keep, like:-
        .Columns("C:K").Delete      ' or .Columns("F").Delete
        ' if you delete individual columns, delete from right to left (!!)
    End With

    ' this part is already done
'    Sheets(2).Activate         ' you don't need to select anything
'    Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
'    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    ' Note that sheets are numbered 1 and up.
    ' Therefore the newly inserted sheet is now # 1
    ' and the previous #1 is now Sheet(2)
    For J = 3 To Sheets.Count
'        Sheets(J).Activate      ' you don't need to activate anything
'        Range("A1").Select      ' you don't need to select anything either
'        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select     ' the Selection is already selected
        With Sheets(J)
            ' Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
            ' It appears that you want to select the range from A2 to lastrow in A -1
            R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(R - 1, "A"))
            ' avoid using the Selection object. Use Range object instead:-
            ' Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
            Rng.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
        End With
    Next J
End Sub
```

Note that you can copy a range comprising several columns in one operation. Just change the definition of the range you copy. This will copy columns A:E.

`Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(R - 1, "E"))`

No other change is required.

Comment: what if i want selected column from both sheets. For example i want column b, d and e  from both sheets. It maybe easier if could select a:e. Could you enlighten me.

Comment: Unless your data sheet is very large (more than 10K rows) I would suggest to copy A:E from all sheets to the "Combined" sheet and delete columns C and A (in that order) after all the copying is done. Else, you can copy each column individually using the same code as above, just add one more `Set Rng` and `Rng.Copy Destination` for each column or set of adjacent columns.

Comment: it doesn't paste as i expected. it just copy the column a and b. Can you run it exactly like my picture above?

Comment: Perhaps I could, and perhaps I couldn't - more likely the latter because I don't have data. I think you now have a new question which you should deal with like a new question. First, study the code and find out where it does something different from what you want. Remove all irrelevant comments in the process. Then try to resolve the issue. Relevant comments in the above code will help you as will the comments in this thread. I think you will be able to resolve the problem, but should you really fail you will be able to point to the precise line of code where you need help.