# PasteSpecial not working - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the data from one worksheet and paste it in another worksheet. But it is not working and asking me to use "A1" or R1C1. But I need to start the pasting from cell A5.

This is the code -

```
 Range("A5:C9").PasteSpecial
```

Kindly share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Do you just need the data? Or are you trying to keep the formulas? If trying to keep the formulas, do you want it *exactly* as is from copy range, or move the formulas relative?  Also, is that all the code? Can you please include the other relevant parts, like the `.Copy` line too?

Comment: just the data sir ! tried paste values but that didn't help as well

Comment: Did you try `Range("A5").PasteSpecial` ? You only need to specify the cell in the top-left corner.Other than that, you have code that cancels the copy operation before you try to pastespecial. Since you decided it was not important enough to include, you are pretty much on your own.

Comment: `Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats` See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34886033/4539709

Comment: i tried Range("A5").PasteSpecial and it didn't help too

Comment: Point 1 of [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."  If that one line is the only code required to reproduce your issue, then it definitely is not going to work - you need to do some sort of `Copy` first!

Comment: @YowE3K Sorry Sir. But I thought if I put in what error message am getting it will be enough, which I have done in my question my saying - it is asking me to use "A1" or R1C1. But failed to highlight the part. Thanks I will keep in my mind.

Comment: That also is an interesting point - what is the exact error message you are getting?  I doubt if it is just `use "A1" or R1C1`, and I've never seen a message similar to that.

Comment: @YowE3K I will add the Screenshot when i go to work tomorrow sir. Just to clarify things. Thanks

Comment: @Sid29 - thanks - my aim in life is to make so many mistakes that I generate every possible Excel error message, so it intrigues me when I hear of one that I haven't accidentally produced before :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to paste the data from one worksheet to another, you can skip `PasteSpecial` (well, `.Copy` altogether) and just set the two ranges equal to another.

```
Worksheets("DESTworksheet").Range([DESTINATION range]).Value = Worksheets("ORIGINworksheet").Range([COPY range]).Value
```

So, try:

```
Worksheets("DestinationSheet").Range("A5:C9").Value = Worksheets("CopyFromSheet").Range("A5:C9").Value
```

Of course changing the worksheet names (and/or ranges) as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Sir. It works