# VBA Copy from workbook and Paste to ThisWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

[image]I am trying to copy a template and paste it into the current workbook. But the code is erroring out. I get a run time error 1004.

```
Sub templateToBBU()

'OPEN TEMPLATE
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
sPath = "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\"
sFile = sPath & "BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

'COPY TEMPLATE PASTE IN BBU DOC
wb.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy 
    After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

End Sub
```

Thanks all,

Comment: What is the does the error say and on which line? See examples here on copy paste http://stackoverflow.com/a/34886033/4539709

Comment: Thank you - I will update my post (run time error 1004)

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: It is erroring here: wb.Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

Comment: You have it as two lines it should be one  or add ` _` at the end of the first to tell vba that it is a continuation.

Comment: Its one line in my code - it appears this way when I pasted into Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code Excel 2016 and It works without problem. It seems It's a known problem for Excel 2003 - 2010 and there is a [workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/tr-tr/help/210684/copying-worksheet-programmatically-causes-run-time-error-1004-in-excel). Save your template file as a Excel Template (xltx) and try as follow:

```
Sub templateToBBU()

'OPEN TEMPLATE
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim sPath As String, sFile As String

sPath = "C:\Users\User123\Desktop\"
sFile = sPath & "Book1.xltx"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add Type:=sFile
End Sub
```

Comment: My code works in all xlsx files, but not xls files. I need it to work in both :/ I cannot seem to get this code to work in this file type.

Comment: SOLUTION: SAVE FILE AS .XLS AND WORKS IN BOTH .XLS/.XLSX