# Loop and Paste special

Tags: vba, excel

I'm copying values as part of one sub process and pasting value through an update button on userform.

To copy values:

```
Private Sub Month1_Click()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("Place on drive")
Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Training1")
    wks.Range("Start:Finish").Copy
wkb.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To paste values in current sheet:

```
Private Sub UpdateActuals_Click()
For i = 1 To 12
If Me.Controls("Month" & i).Value = True Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2017 Actuals").Range(i+1, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

If I replace "i+1, 5" with "B5", it errors with

> "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".

I feel as if values copied in one sub process are not brought to second one, would that be correct?

Also, how do I reduce processing time given that I have 12 months (12 files) in various places that I can't change the location for...

Comment: 1) Copy | Paste should be done in same module. After copy is done in first sub it's wiped out as soon as sub ends. 2) *how do i reduce processing time* - please limit your questions to one specific issue, it's more helpful for everyone that way. (see [ask] for more info)

Comment: Also, instead of using Copy/Paste you can just use a simple assignment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2017 Actuals").Range(i+1, 5) = wks.Range("Start:Finish")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886033/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Range usually likes a starting cell and an ending cell.  I suggest since you are looking at just one cell that you change .Range to .Cells.  If you really want to use a range with RC format, .Range(Cells(row1, col1), Cells(row2, col2)), if you want just one cell then you can make the two parts the same.  I have run into problems before using Range and only one cell definition before, either make it .Cells for your target or fill out Range the way I have explained.. Cheers.

```
Dim 2017actWS AS Worksheet
Set 2017actWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2017 Actuals")
```

1)

```
2017actWS.Cells(i+1, 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

-or-

2)

```
2017actWS.Range(2017actWS.Cells(i+1, 5), 2017actWS.Cells(i+1,5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

**When using Ranges excel will often throw errors if they are not the same size in a copy and paste, you can eliminate that by using a single cell as the starting target of your paste with .Cells**

Also I don't see you call your function.  You will want your paste close to your copy or you might find things get strange (suggestion: just after your copy).

Edited to be sure there is not worksheeet ambiguity. Thank you Scott C.

Cheers, WWC

Comment: Your  second answer will error if the sheets("2017 Actuals") is not the active sheet as the cells inside the range will be referencing a different sheet.

Comment: got it, good catch, helped out with some better programming practice along the way, never leave it to chance.