# Copy, But Paste only the values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to copy data based on filters.
But some cells that are being copied from already have formulas in them, so I want to copy that and paste only as text or values.I tried using the below. I tried xlValues and Format text, both of them giving errors - Run Time error '438' . Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Sub DS()

    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim sourceWorkbookPath As String
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    Dim lastRow As Long



    ' Define workbooks paths
    sourceWorkbookPath = "Exceptional Transfer -2020 v2.xlsm"
    targetWorkbookPath = "template2.xlsx"

    ' Set a reference to the target Workbook and sheets
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' definr worksheet's names for each workbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("B")



    With sourceSheet

        ' Get last row
         lastRow = .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="PENDING"
        .Range("A1:Q1").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="U3R", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="U2R"

        .Range("K2:K" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("A1")
        .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("B1")
        .Range("E2:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("E1").PasteSpecial xlValues
        .Range("G2:G" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("F1")
        .Range("S2:S" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("I1")
        .Range("T2:T" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("J1")
        .Range("U2:U" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("C1")



    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    sourceSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @BigBen ......I used this link to find out xlPasteValues.....but it is not working in my code...that is why I posted a question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886033/4539709

Comment: Don't use the `Destination` method. use `Range.PasteSpecial` (i.e. copy on one line and paste on completely separate line)

Comment: Hi @0m3r It doesn't work.....I tried this          .Range("E2:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                     Destination:=targetSheet.Range("E1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: remove the ` _
                                     Destination:=` and have two separate lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the one-liner copy/paste with `Destination` and switch over to the multi-line copy/paste method which gives you access to the `.PasteSpecial` property

---

```
'Copy here
.Range("K2:K" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'Paste here
targetSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Hi @urdearboy This worked....Can you give me the reason why was this happening? Also I'm only changing this for the Range which has formulas....that is fine , right?

Comment: `Range.Copy Destination` does not have access to the `PasteSpecial` properties so you were calling a property that did not exist

Comment: Well technically the `PasteSpecial` method, not property.